# Field 'isTextEllipsized' from Label component not working - Roku Scenegraph

Tags: roku, brightscript, scenegraph

As I said on the title the field isTextEllipsized is not working for me, is always returning false.

Example:

```
label = m.top.createChild("Label")
label.color = "#ffffff"
label.font = font
label.vertAlign = "bottom"
label.wrap = true
label.lineSpacing = 2
label.width = 135
label.height = 61
label.text = "Really really really really really really long long long long long text"

? "label.isTextEllipsized " label.isTextEllipsized
```

Console prints:

> label.isTextEllipsized false

**Note: Using Roku 4210x - OS 7.2**

Answer (score 1):

Please add the below code to solve this issue

```
label.ellipsizeOnBoundary = "true"
```

I know that this may not help you but I'm adding for future referrers

Answer (score 0):

Has the label been rendered on screen yet? I.e. has SG had a chance to set isTextEllipsized.

If so, it might be a bug, see
http://forums.roku.com/viewtopic.php?f=34&t=94601

Answer (score 0):

also, might be that because you set color incorrectly:

"#ffffff" should be "0xFFFFFFFF"

Just an outside guess, but because it's a string, it might accept it, but silently cause the component to fail.